# React styled component child prop selector

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

is it possible to make selector for child component prop in styled components?

```
<Accordion>
   <Checkbox checked='false' />
   <Text>Text to be hidden when checked is false</Text>
</Accordion>
```

I would like to access the prop something like this:

```
const Accordion = styled.div`
    & > ${Checkbox}[checked='false'] ~ ${Text} {
        display: none;
    }
`;
```

Is it possible and if so, how should I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use [Attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors), so you need to define valid attributes on `Checkbox` component like [`data-*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*).

If you trying to use component's property, you have to lift the state up (see `Text` with "State from Parent").

```
const Checkbox = styled.div``;
const Text = styled.div``;

const Accordion = styled.div`
  & > ${Checkbox}[data-checked="true"] ~ ${Text} {
    color: palevioletred;
    font-weight: 600;
    &:last-child {
      color: ${prop => (prop.checked ? `blue` : `orange`)};
    }
  }
  & > ${Text}[title="example"]{
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
`;

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Accordion checked>
      <Checkbox data-checked="true" checked="true">
        I'm Check box
      </Checkbox>
      <Text title="example">With attr gives border</Text>
      <Text>Without attr</Text>
      <Text>State from Parent</Text>
    </Accordion>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit quiet-tree-lnukc]

Comment: Thank you! Which approach would you recommend? I guess to lift the state I need to define the method outside the Accordion component which would make it not reusable, and I would need to copy the method every time I implement the accordion, right?

Comment: There is no "better" approach, the state is dynamic, pick what fits your use case.